# How to return a selected itemvalue from listbox from one module to another?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, listbox, return

i want to return the selected item from a listbox from one module into another. Inside `A.py` i call a function from `B.py` which creates a small tkinter `listbox`. Within this listbox i want to select an item, and return it as a value to `A.py`.

I tried several things, i.e.

```
# inside A.py
import B

filter = B.get_pt_filter()
```

and

```
# inside B.py
from tkinter import * # (i know this is not clean, but let's keep it this way for now)
from functools import partial


def button_click(lb):    
    return lb.get(lb.curselection())

def get_pt_filter():
    pt_list = define_pt_list()
    # create window
    tk_window = Tk()
    tk_window.title('Choose')
    tk_window.geometry('350x400')
    # listbox border
    frame_listbox = Frame(master=tk_window, bg='#FFCFC9')
    frame_listbox.place(x=5, y=5, width=335, height=360)
    # button border
    frame_button = Frame(master=tk_window, bg='#D5E88F')
    frame_button.place(x=5, y=370, width=335, height=30)
    # Listbox
    lb = Listbox(master=frame_listbox, selectmode='browse')
    for pt in pt_list:
        lb.insert('end', pt)
        lb.place(x=5, y=5, width=325, height=350)
    # Label Text
    labelText = Label(master=frame_button, bg='white')
    labelText.place(x=5, y=5, width=325, height=20)
    # button_choose = Button(master=frame_button, text='Choose', command= lambda: button_click(lb))
    action_with_arg = partial(button_click, lb)
    button_choose = Button(master=frame_button, text='Choose', command=action_with_arg)
    button_choose .place(x=5, y=5, width=325, height=20)
    # Aktivierung des Fensters
    tk_window.wait_window()

def define_pt_list():
    return [
        'apple'
    ]
```

So far i get the value i want in `button_click` but i fail to return it to module `A.py` and assign it to `filter`. How would i do that? What am i missing here?

I've tried several things including a `return button_choose` at the end of `get_pt_filter` or lambda functions behind `command` while creating `Button`. I can not break the Loop however, and i'm stuck forever it seems like. Also i tried `tk_window.mainloop()` and `tk_window.wait_window()`. None of those work.

**In Short**: How do i assign "apple" to filter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the problem here is that although `lb.get(lb.curselection())` does actually evaluate to `"apple"`, `button_click` has nowhere to return that value. You can verify this by having the `button_click` function printing instead of returning. In order to use as much of the code you've already written i suggests that you create a global variable in `button_click`, e.g.:

```
def button_click(lb):
    global selection
    selection = lb.get(lb.curselection())
```

Then you can access the variable `selection` in `get_pt_filter` and thus return it from there with `return selection`.

To make sure that the 'choose'-button actually closes the window, you should make the 'root' global as well:

```
global tk_window
tk_window = Tk()
```

and finish `button_click` of with `tk_window.quit()`, so the function ends up looking like this:

```
def button_click(lb):   
    global selection
    selection = lb.get(lb.curselection())
    tk_window.quit()
```

Also replace `tk_window.wait_window()` with `tk_window.mainloop()`.

This is a bit of a hacky solution, but it fits the code you already wrote.

**A better solution** would be to store the application in a class that has it's own variables that can be accessed by `button_click`. Have a look at [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17466561/best-way-to-structure-a-tkinter-application). I suggest the following application to accomplish what you need without using `global`:

```
from tkinter import *

class get_pt_filter:
    def __init__(self, parent, pt_list):
        # create window
        self.tk_window = parent
        self.tk_window.title('Choose')
        self.tk_window.geometry('350x400')
        # listbox border
        frame_listbox = Frame(master=self.tk_window, bg='#FFCFC9')
        frame_listbox.place(x=5, y=5, width=335, height=360)
        # button border
        frame_button = Frame(master=self.tk_window, bg='#D5E88F')
        frame_button.place(x=5, y=370, width=335, height=30)
        # Listbox
        self.lb = Listbox(master=frame_listbox, selectmode='browse')
        for pt in pt_list:
            self.lb.insert('end', pt)
            self.lb.place(x=5, y=5, width=325, height=350)
        # Label Text
        labelText = Label(master=frame_button, bg='white')
        labelText.place(x=5, y=5, width=325, height=20)
        button_choose = Button(master=frame_button, text='Choose', command=self.button_click)
        button_choose.place(x=5, y=5, width=325, height=20)

    def button_click(self):   
        self.selection = self.lb.get(self.lb.curselection())
        self.tk_window.quit()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    parent = Tk()
    get = get_pt_filter(parent, ['apple', 'pear'])
    # Aktivierung des Fensters
    parent.mainloop()

    #access the selection
    print(get.selection)
```

When `mainloop` quits you can access the `selection` varaible of the instance.

Comment: Thanks, this one is working so far. Although it is indeed a bit hacky - there must be a solution without globals aswell, no?! Anyways, upvoted and accepted for presenting a solution.

Comment: Typically you would structure your tkinter application in a class. This way you can have `button_click` change a variable in the class instance. [This thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17466561/best-way-to-structure-a-tkinter-application) might be able to clarify how an application can be structured.